# How to properly implement CRUD json fields in laravel

Tags: laravel, crud

With the following code, I dynamically add fields for a different number of product properties:

```
$("#addRow").click(function () {
 var html = '';
 html += '<div id="inputFormRow">';
 html += '<div class="input-group mb-3">';
 html += '<input type="text" name="properties[{{i}}][key]" class="form-control m-input ml-3" value="{{ old('properties['.$i.'][key]') }}" placeholder="Key" autocomplete="off">';
 html += '<input type="text" name="properties[{{i}}][value]" class="form-control m-input ml-3" value="{{ old('properties['.$i.'][value]') }}" placeholder="Value" autocomplete="off">';
 html += '<div class="input-group-append ml-3">';
 html += '<button id="removeRow" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>';
 html += '</div>';
 html += '</div>';
        
 $('#newRow').append(html);
});

  // remove row
$('#removeRow').on('click', function () {
 $(this).closest('#inputFormRow').remove();
});
```

And here is my html

```
@isset($product)
 @foreach($product->properties as $i=>$prod)
   <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="text" name="properties[{{ $i }}][key]" value="{{ $prod[$i]['key'] }}" class="form-control m-input ml-3" placeholder="Key" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="properties[{{ $i }}][value]" value="{{ $prod[$i]['value'] }}" class="form-control m-input ml-3" placeholder="Value" autocomplete="off">
   <div class="input-group-append ml-3">
   <button id="removeRow" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 @endforeach
@endisset

<div id="newRow"></div>
<button id="addRow" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Add field</button>
```

But I can't make a dynamic counter and how can you edit these fields later? How to add/remove? I found a lesson where I got the idea with this implementation, but for simplicity they took a fixed number of fields, which is easy, but how to do it with dynamic fields?

Comment: these dynamic fields are better handled with `vue.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First** (for dynamic counter)
Add this `i` variable before `addRow` selector. Then increase it inside the `.click()` function

```js
let i = 0;
$("#addRow").click(function () {
    i++;
   // now do your append() code
}
```

**Second** (add/remove row)
Html+jquery code for adding row is already there. `(Your Remove code may not work for multiple non-unique id)` For removing a row, add a `button` below `<div id="inputFormRow">` this line with a class say `dynamic-remove` like this:

```html
<div id="inputFormRow">
<button type="button" class="dynamic-remove">Remove</button>
```

Then add jquery code for onclick on this button:

```js
$('.dynamic-remove').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().remove()
})
```

**Third** (editing dynamic row)
use a foreach and place your html code which you are appending and populate them:

```php
@foreach($model_array as $i => $model)
    // your html code populated via $model object
@endforeach
```